# How to Scroll a ListView in android programatically to up to down gesture

Tags: android, listview, loader, pull-to-refresh

I am newbie to android and have implemented pull to refresh and a custom ListView in my demo app. I am deleting an item from listItem class,when I am dong pull to refresh that item is removed from my ListView but it must needed to do that,I want to remove that item once deleted.I have tried notifyDatasetChange which will not work in my case.So I want to do pulling my list to down programatically so list will be refresh,Please help me to do it.Thank you

```
public class TimelineFragment extends BaseFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Post>>, OnRefreshListener, OnScrollListener {
    private static boolean inBackground = false;

    public static android.widget.PopupMenu popupMenu;
    private int index = -1;
    private int top = 0;
    public static TimelineAdapter mTimelineAdapter;
    public TimelineLoader mTimelineLoader;
    public PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;
    public static ListView mListViewTimeline;
    ProgressBar mProgressBarLoading;
    TextView mTextViewNoItems;
    ImageView im;
    Menu mm;
    int total;
    Activity activity;
    private int hot_number = 0;
    private TextView ui_hot = null;

    int lastPosition;
    int lastTop;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    private boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
        return isInBackground;
    }

    public void updateHotCount(final int new_hot_number) {
        hot_number = new_hot_number;
        if (ui_hot == null) return;

        if (new_hot_number == 0)
            ui_hot.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else {
            ui_hot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ui_hot.setText(Integer.toString(new_hot_number));
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (isAppIsInBackground(getActivity())) {

            Log.d("ACTION", "RETURN FROM BACGRKOUDN");
            getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, TimelineFragment.this);
        }
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

if(mTimelineLoader != null) {
    mTimelineLoader.stopLoading();
}
        lastPosition = mListViewTimeline.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = mListViewTimeline.getChildAt(0);
        lastTop = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

//       lastPosition = mListViewTimeline.getSelectedItemPosition();
//       int lastPositionInGroup = lastPosition - mListViewTimeline.getFirstVisiblePosition();
//       lastTop = mListViewTimeline.getChildAt( lastPositionInGroup ).getTop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_post, menu);

        final View menu_hotlist = menu.findItem(R.id.activity22).getActionView();
        ui_hot = (TextView) menu_hotlist.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Notifications", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        updateHotCount(preferences.getInt("notifications", 0));    

        new MyMenuItemStuffListener(menu_hotlist, "Show hot message") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("View_mode", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };   
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.search22) {
            //   Log.d("MyApp", "action bar clicked");    

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchPostActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("View_mode", true);
            startActivity(intent);    
        }
        if (id == R.id.activity22) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("View_mode", true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        total = 0;
        mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ptr_layout);
        ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity()).allChildrenArePullable().listener(this).setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);

        mProgressBarLoading = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBarLoading);
        mTextViewNoItems = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewNoItems);

        mTimelineAdapter = new TimelineAdapter(getActivity());

        mListViewTimeline = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewTimeline);
        mListViewTimeline.setEmptyView(mProgressBarLoading);

        mListViewTimeline.setAdapter(mTimelineAdapter);
        mTimelineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mListViewTimeline.setOnScrollListener(this);
        //  mListViewTimeline.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        mListViewTimeline.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

         activity = getActivity();

        if(activity != null) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, TimelineFragment.this);
                    //Do something after 100ms
                }
            }, 1000);

            mTextViewNoItems.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);

                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, TimelineFragment.this);
                    Log.d("CLICK", "REFRESH");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Post>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        mTimelineLoader = new TimelineLoader(getActivity(), mListViewTimeline);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return mTimelineLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Post>> arg0, List<Post> data) {    
        mTimelineAdapter.setData(data);

        mTimelineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
        mTextViewNoItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBarLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mListViewTimeline.setEmptyView(mTextViewNoItems);

        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);

            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, TimelineFragment.this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Post>> arg0) {
        mTimelineAdapter.setData(null);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {

        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        mTextViewNoItems.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mProgressBarLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mListViewTimeline.setEmptyView(mProgressBarLoading);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount && visibleItemCount != 0) {
            if (mTimelineLoader.loadMore() && !mTimelineLoader.loading()) {
                total = totalItemCount - 1;
                lastPosition = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                View v = view.getChildAt(0);
                lastTop = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
                mTimelineLoader.onContentChanged();   
            }    
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code to your activity class to get the instance of it in another class and to refresh your ListView:

```
private static MainActivity instance;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    instance = this;
}

public static MainActivity getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

public void refreshListView(){
    mTimelineAdapter = new TimelineAdapter(getActivity());
    mListViewTimeline.setAdapter(mTimelineAdapter);
    mTimelineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You can now call `refreshListView()` from the class where you are removing your row using following code:

```
// call this after removal to refresh the List View
MainActivity.getInstance().refreshListView();
```

Comment: but i am deleting item from seperate class.ListItem is a seperate class.so where to put this code?

Comment: I have added this lines in my listItem class but not done.>:(

Comment: can i use it in fragment also,As I am having fragment in place of activity.

Comment: Yes, you can use it in Fragment, but change instance variable of MainActivity to private static YourFragment instance; and return the same in getInstance(), and call method via YourFragment.getInstance().refreshListView(), rest of the code is same.

Comment: And please don't forget to vote up and accept my answer if it really helped you.

Comment: Thanks, but tell me the issue, I'll try to solve it.

Comment: i have solved it.!! by calling resume after deleting the item.

Comment: I hope, it might have helped you or given you an idea to solve your issue. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your ListView in SwipeRefreshLayout and it will implement the up to down gesture.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html

Example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and in your activity java code

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout =(SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
                //Do something here
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); // For end refreshing animation
        }        
});
```